# Distributing Apple App to multinational client

Tags: ios

I've opened an Enterprise Account and I need to deploy an Application to a multinational client.
The problem I'm facing is that my enterprise developer account is Italian, but the client needs the Application in several sites in Poland, China and USA.

What's the best approach in this case?
Is there a way to deploy the app without uploading it inton the Public Apple store?
Thanks everyone

Comment: Had forgot this question. I've solved this by myself and I'm going to leave the explanation here, hope it helps someone.

After reading apple documentation and having calls with their customer center I've been suggested that both the seller and the buyer open an Apple Developer Account Enterprise.
The seller then publishes the product on the VPP store, and the buyer can buy the amount of copies they want.

Please note that, the copies bought from a national VPP store work ONLY on Apple IDs of the same nationality.
I also suggest to use an MDM to manage devices and apps

Comment: In my case I've published on the VPP store my app, the price set to free.
Then I've whitelisted the buyer's company Apple developer Account Enterprise  (one for each nation) and they bought the copies they needed.
They use AirWatch to manage their devices, so it was easy for them to assign the app to their devices